# Determine if the series is convergent or divergent by using limit comparison

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

The series is
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{2n^2-1}{3n^5+2n+1}$$

I used the comparison method to solve which gave me
$b_n=\frac{2n^2}{3n^5+2n}$, then I put those two into a limit with $\frac{a_n}{b_n}$

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\frac{2n^2-1}{3n^5+2n+1}}{\frac{2n^2}{3n^5+2n}}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{2n^2-1}{3n^5+2n-1}*\frac{3n^5+2n}{2n^2}=$$

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{2n^2-1\left(3n^5+2n\right)}{3n^5+2n+1\left(2n^2\right)}$$
After canceling out terms I'm left with $\lim_{n\to\infty}-1$ which means the series diverges but the answer says it should converge. Did I mess up with the cross multiplication or somewhere else?

Comment: "which means the series diverges" Why is that? $\sum_n b_n$ converges.

Comment: You can use L’Hopital’s rule to show the series converges. Ignoring all terms with degree lower than the highest degree on both the numerator and denominator , we get  2n^2/3n^5=2/3n^3 so the series converges.

Comment: @Jazzowner Come on, you don't need L'Hopital and the differentiations it requires to solve that one...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a serious error in your computation. Note that\begin{align}\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{2n^2-1}{3n^5+2n-1}\cdot\frac{3n^5+2n}{2n^2}&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{6n^7+\text{terms of lower degree}}{6n^7+\text{terms of lower degree}}\\&=1.\end{align}Therefore, the series converges.

Note that the limit could not possibly be negative, since each $a_n$ and each $b_n$ is positive.

On the other hand, it is much more natural to take $b_n=\dfrac1{n^3}$ instead.

Comment: There is an error, but even at a high level: given the choice of $b_n$, *even if the limit had indeed been $-1$ the conclusion would have been convergence.* That is some deeper mistake from the OP's than just a computation one, I would say.

Comment: Yes, you are right.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos so the final fraction should be $\frac{6n^7-3n^5+4n^3-2n}{6n^7+4n^3+2n^2}$? I know that doesn't equal 1 so I'm just wondering how I keep messing up.

Comment: @EricBrown Yes, that's what the final fraction looks like.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos so then how does it equal 1 if I still have a $-3n^5$ in the numerator and a $2n$ in the denominator?

Comment: Because$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{6n^7-3n^5+4n^3-2n}{6n^7+4n^3+2n^2}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{6-3/n^2+4/n^4-2/n^6}{6+4/n^4+2/n^5}=\frac66=1.$$

Comment: @EricBrown There is a bit of abuse of notation at the end; it's not *equal* to one, it has a *limit equal to one.*

Comment: @ClementC. Ok, thank you very much :)

Comment: I've edited my answer. There is no abuse of notation anymore.

Answer (score 2):

The series converges. First show that for all $n$ sufficiently large, $a_n\geq 0$. Then show for all $n$ sufficiently large, $a_n\leq \frac{1}{n^2}$. Now you can use comparison test.

By "sufficiently large", $n\geq 10$ will do just fine.

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{2n^2-1}{3n^5+2n+1}=\frac{2n^2(1-\frac{1}{2n^2})}{3n^5(1+\frac{2}{3n^4}+\frac{1}{3n^5})}$$

$$\sim \frac{2}{3n^\color{red}{3}}$$

$\color{red}{3}>1$ so, it is a positive convergent series.

Answer (score 0):

Step by step $$0\leq \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{2n^2-1}{3n^5+2n+1}\leq\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{2n^2}{3n^5+2n+1}\\\leq\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{2n^2}{3n^5+2n}\leq\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{2n^2}{3n^5}=\frac23\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{n^3}$$so 
$$0\leq \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{2n^2-1}{3n^5+2n+1}\leq \frac23\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{n^3}$$

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, you forgot to uses parentheses where required in
$\frac{2n^2-1\left(3n^5+2n\right)}{3n^5+2n+1\left(2n^2\right)}$, which should be $\frac{\color{red}(2n^2-1\color{red})\left((3n^5+2n\right)}{\color{red}(3n^5+2n+1\color{red})\left(2n^2\right)}$.

This being will be simpler  using *symptotic equivalents*: near $\infty$ a polynomial is equivalent to its leading term, and equivalence is compatible with multiplication and division, so
$$ \frac{2n^2-1}{3n^5+2n+1}\sim_{n\to\infty}\frac{2n^2}{3n^5}=\frac23\frac1{n^3},$$
and the latter is the general term of a convergent $p$-series.